# Disable Submit Button in Gravity Forms (Conditional Fields)

Tags: jquery, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have to be missing something simple.  I'm trying to set the submit button to disabled until all required fields are completed.  It's working as expected except for the required fields that are conditionally shown.

Here is my code:

```
    //Disable the GF submit button until all required fields are completed
  $('form[id^="gform_"]').on('change', function (e) {
      var $reqd = $(this).find('.gfield_contains_required').filter(function (i, c) {
        return []
          .concat($(c).find('input[type="text"], input[type="email"], textarea').filter(function (i, fl) { return $(fl).val().length == 0; }).get())
          .concat($(c).find('select').get())
          .concat($(c).find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').get())
          .length;
      });
      alert($reqd.length);
      if ($reqd.length) {
        $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').addClass('disabled button-disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
        $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').removeClass('disabled button-disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    }).trigger('change');
```

The problem is that the required hidden fields are being counted.  I tried to use `$(this).find('.gfield_contains_required').is(':visible')` but it throws a console error that it's not a function.

Comment: Instead of `is(':visible')`, try `filter(':visible')`, or change the selector to `.gfield_contains_required:visible`.